# How to split - awk

Tags: awk

I was wondering if I can make lists having left characters OR right characters after splitting with '=', and finally each character also get splitted with another '|' and ','. I have tried but failed because the number of lists are not fixed. Even C16 can be shown up, then it will be 16 item in the input.

Can you give me any hint?

Input

```
C1=34,C2=35,C3="99"
```

Output

```
C1|C2|C3#34,35,"99"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass multiple characters as the delimiter when using `-F`. The command could look like this:

```
awk -F'[,=]' '{printf "%s|%s|%s#%s,%s,%s", $1,$3,$5,$2,$4,$6}' input.txt
```

I'm using `,` and `=` as the delimiter. This makes it simple to access individual values and reassemble them using `printf`.

If the number of columns is unknown, you need to loop over the columns. First over the odd columns which are the names, then over the even columns which are the values. I suggest to put it into a script:

*test.awk*

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[,=]"
} 
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2){
        if(i>=NF-1){
            fmt="%s"
        }else{
            fmt="%s|"
        }
        printf fmt,$i
    }   
    printf "#" 
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){
        if(i>=NF-1){
            fmt="%s"
        }else{
            fmt="%s,"
        }
        printf fmt,$i
    }   
}
```

Then execute it like this:

```
awk -f test.awk input.txt
```

Comment: I understand your solution. By the way, what if there are so many item(characters) and we can't predict?

Comment: Then you need a loop. The odd columns are the names, the even columns are the values.

Comment: I've added an example

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'[=,]' '
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) {
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<(NF-1)?"|":"#")
    }
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) {
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF?",":ORS)
    }
}
' file
C1|C2|C3#34,35,"99"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk '{sub(/C1=34,C2=35,C3="99"/,"C1|C2|C3#34,35,\"99\"")}1' file 
    C1|C2|C3#34,35,"99"
```